# BizTalk Iteration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I currently have a repeating XML segment and from within this segment I am passing multiple fields into a scripting functoid. The scripting functoid contains inline c# which can return a range of different results. I am looking to iterate only when a certain result is found (ZD01), if ZD01 isn't the output then it will simply pass through what the output actually is. I am currently iterating the repeating segment which give me something like below

```
ZD01 = 1

ZD02 = ZD02

ZD01 = 3

ZD01 = 4

ZD02 = ZD02

ZD01 = 6
```

What I would like to achieve is

```
ZD01 = 1

ZD02 = ZD02

ZD01 = 2

ZD01 = 3

ZD02 = ZD02

ZD01 = 4
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom xslt instead of the BizTalk mapper for complex maps and repeating nodes.

An example how to create a custom xslt.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KZlfOqyfEQ